# Creating latebinding approach in vba using selenium

Tags: vba, excel, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Is it possible to create latebinding approach using vba in combination with selenium? If it is then how that would be? I searched a lot but could not find any match. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Something like below:

```
Sub Test_Selenium()
    Dim post As Object

    With CreateObject("ChromeDriver") ''it's a faulty approach as I'm not familiar with it
        .get "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
        For Each post In .FindElementsByCss(".question-hyperlink")
            r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = post.Text
        Next post
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

And it produces the common error

> activeX component can't create object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
Sub Test_Selenium()
    Dim post As Object

    With CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
        .get "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
        For Each post In .FindElementsByCss(".question-hyperlink")
            r = r + 1: Cells(r, 1) = post.Text
        Next post
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

But if at all possible, you would be better off using early binding.